# update row if already exist or else insert new record in table using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, sql-update, sql-insert

```
SELECT * FROM user_referral;

id     user_id    new_user_id   bonus_type        amount 
1      123                         own             25 
2      234                         own             25    
3      123         456            referral         25    

SELECT * FROM user_points;
id          user_id           referral_points                  
 1          123                     50       
 2          234                     25
```

I am working for an application and I have two tables like above. If user join my application than he will get some bonus.

when user join he get 25 rupees and when he refer another friend again he get 25 more.So first record will come to **user_referral** table where individual amount will be stored and for particular user total amount will be stored in **user_points** table.

Now I am writing trigger in **user_referral** table to update amount in user_points table using mysql, I want to check if user already exist in **user_points** table that amount should be updated else it should insert new record.

I tried if else condition but its not working, I don't know how to check duplicate records..

```
if (SELECT user_id FROM user_points WHERE user_id IN (SELECT new.user_id FROM user_referral)) then
update user_points set
referral_points=referral_points+new.point,
updated_time=new.inserted_time;
else
INSERT INTO user_points (user_id,referral_points,updated_time)
VALUES (new.user_id, new.point, new.inserted_time);
end if;
```

Also I tried using on duplicate key update, but in my case it is inserting new row instead it should update previous one.

Any help will be appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

Consider the `insert ... on duplicate key` syntax:

```
insert into user_points(user_id, referral_points)
values(:user_id, :referral_points)
on duplicate key update referral_points = referral_points + values(referral_points)
```

For this to work, you need a unique constraint on `user_points(user_id)`.

When an `insert` occurs on a `user_id` that already exists, MySQL goes to the `on duplicate key` clause, where the new `referral_points` value is added to the existing value.

Comment: I will try then making unique constraints, I forgot to keep unique constraints